# boot from USB. How can I do

Tags: boot, usb

How can I boot UBUNTU installer from USB stick? I did it last year I don't remember how. I used a software from windows. In bios setup menu there is not 'USB' in the options

Comment: software from Windows=UNetbootin, BIOS option=USB HDD

Comment: use ubuntu.com's install with USB - option

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can just download the ubuntu iso from the www.ubuntu.com site. Then you can use UNetbootin as @karel indicated. There are a few different tools to write iso's to usb sticks.

I have not used windows in a while. You could also just download the iso to windows, and then use a drive emulator like [Daemon Tools](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/downloads) to mount the iso as if it was a drive. Then you can open Ubuntu and check it out. If you still want to create a USB, then you can click on the Ubuntu Dash and type in "startup disk creator." The startup disk creator has the option of install ubuntu to a usb stick. Once you write the iso to the USB stick, you can reboot and load from the usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

You can find good tutorials for all important Operating Systems at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install at right hand side.
Canonical explains how-to create a bootable USB stick.

Answer (score 0):

important is this, before you install *.iso - image on to
your usb-stick,

this usb-stick needs to be formatted with boot-flag !

first format in gparted, - then add boot-flag to it !

Answer (score 0):

Use this link of ubuntu.com, which there is tutorial about making USB - bootable:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows